# json and how to work with it

Tags: jquery, json

say I have the following json object;

```
{'fname':'john', 'lname':'Locke'}
```

and the following text boxes

```
<input type="text" name="txtFirstName" value="" />
<input type="text" name="txtLastName" value="" />
```

how do I go ahead and assign these textboxes the values in the json object with jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$("input[@name='txtFirstName']").val(jsonObject.fname);
$("input[@name='txtLastName']").val(jsonObject.lname);
```